# how to create a deep link for FireStore content?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link

In my android app, I have some user posts like in social media posts with some text, photo, and some additional details.

What I need is when user clicks on the share button it will create a dynamic or deep-link to that specific post.

I had stored some posts in Firestore and some in Realtime Database. How to create dynamic links to the specific posts?

I had seen the developer page, but not found how to achieve this. Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL parameters in your Firebase Dynamic links and with that determine what post to show in the app when it's opened by a dynamic link.

For example such an URL:

```
Uri.parse('https://your.page.link/view_post/?postID=${post.uid}'
```

Comment: Do you mean `postID` means Document id?

Comment: Yes. Or any kind of id defining a post. You can also add some kind of `path` data to the params to be more flexible and open `comments` or other parts of your app.